# Where can I ask about "Productivity tools"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask about productivity tools, e.g. "todo lists", and "calendars" applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://productivity.stackexchange.com/ was probably the best fit. It is likely your question has already been asked there. It [has been shutdown](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity) because of a lack of activity, though.

Answer (score -1):

You would ask on the [*Software Recommendations* Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site for recommendations about which software to use, but you would usually ask on the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) Stack Exchange site for information about how to use that software.

Depending on your question, you may also want to consider the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. Depending on which application/platform your question is about, there may be a specialized Stack Exchange, e.g. the [*Android Enthusiasts*](https://android.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You need to provide more information about how this fits. In fact, it is not on topic to ask about how to use (for example) the iOS calendar app on Software Recs.

Comment: You're right. Done.